# Does $\sum\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Does the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}$ converge?

The ratio test is inconclusive since the limit of $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is $1$ where $a_n=\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}$. Also, according to this question:
[limit of $\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248881/limit-of-frac2n4nn2/248918), the limit of $a_n$ is $0$, so this gives no information. Also it seems that the integral test and the root test are not useful to this problem. This question [Does $\sum\frac{4^n(n!)^2}{(2n)!}$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016076/does-sum-frac4nn22n-converge/2016091) is kind of relevant, but I couldn't get any help from this one.

Comment: $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$ is $2n \choose n$, so maybe that might help?

Comment: Of interest: The term $\frac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}$ can also be written $\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}}$, the probability that a 1-dimensional random walk has returned to the origin after exactly $2n$ steps. The _sum_ therefore is the expected number of times the random walk will _ever_ return. It would be $1/p-1$ if the probability for the random walk to _never return_ was $p>0$. So knowing that this series diverges is the same as knowing that a 1D random walk returns _almost surely_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(2n)!/(n!)^2$ is the central binomial coefficient of the $2n$th row of Pascal’s triangle, which makes it greater than the average value along that row, namely $2^{2n}/(2n+1)$.  That means the terms of your series exceed $1/(2n+1)$, whose series is divergent.

Answer (score 3):

Using Stirling’s formula, we get $a_n$ equivalent to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$. Since $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ diverges, your series diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Using the generalized binomial theorem, you can show $$(1-4x)^{-1/2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n} x^n$$ which converges for $|x|<1/4$.  Taking the limit as $x\to 1/4$ from the left (noting the coefficients are positive so the power series is increasing on $(0,1/4)$) shows your series diverges to $\infty$.